# How to force download a file using node js?

Tags: node.js, express, download

My concept is like that,I will send a request from frontend along with few params to backend (nodejs, express). Backend will check params info then will generate a downloadable link that user will be able to download without knowing the downloadable link.

I am expecting,
User will send: *[www.something.com/param?key=23232323](http://www.something.com/param?key=23232323)*
Backend will verify the key and will generate *[www.something.com/download/image.zip](http://www.something.com/download/image.zip)* (that should be unknown by user).
User will get image.zip file. That download link should not be exposed.
Any other idea is appreciable.